# Does the FlowDocument contain any user text?

Tags: wpf, xaml, flowdocument

How can you tell if a FlowDocument contains any text that the user typed in or not?

I have an application that auto-commits changes for each screen. I want to know if the FlowDocument obtained from a RichTextBox contains any user input or if it is blank. I convert the FlowDocument to binary xaml and commit it to db. If the FlowDocument contains no user text then I do not want to add a new FlowDocument to the db.

I don't want to parse the xaml to check if there is any user text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is:

```
var range = new TextRange(flowDocument.ContentStart, flowDocument.ContentEnd);
if (!range.IsEmpty)
{
    // commit changes
}
```

Comment: This only checks if FlowDocument is empty. OP may have pre-existing document in which case your method would give false positive even if user didn't touch the document.

Comment: Ah, wait, you ARE the OP! :) So you must know better what problem you are trying to solve. You question is "How to check if FlowDocument is empty", and not "Does FlowDocument contain any user text".